# How to insert into Table B, all rows from Table B, but with one column changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I'm trying to duplicate every row of, but with one column having a different value. The problem is getting that value involves another table which has no current relation.

Table Search:

| SearchID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A 1 |
| 2 | B 1 |
| 3 | C 1 |
| 4 | A 2 |
| 5 | B 2 |
| 6 | C 2 |

Table SearchFields:

| SearchFieldID | SearchID | Foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bob |
| 2 | 1 | mary |
| 3 | 2 | tim |
| 4 | 2 | justin |
| 5 | 3 | jay |
| 6 | 3 | anthony |

What I'm trying to get is Table SearchFields to look like this:

Table Expected SearchFields:

| SearchFieldID | SearchID | Foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bob |
| 2 | 1 | mary |
| 3 | 2 | tim |
| 4 | 2 | justin |
| 5 | 3 | jay |
| 6 | 3 | anthony |
| 7 | 4 | bob |
| 8 | 4 | mary |
| 9 | 5 | tim |
| 10 | 5 | justin |
| 11 | 6 | jay |
| 12 | 6 | anthony |

The only relation I can see is part of the `Name` column on Search (everything up to the last space gives me duplicate rows, and I can take the higher SearchId from each duplicate to give me the new SearchId to use)

So far I've been able to do things like:

```sql
select 
    max(search.searchid) [SearchId],
    substring(  name, 
                1, 
                len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name))) [Name] 
from search
group by 
    substring( name, 
                1, 
                len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name)))
```

This gives me

| SearchID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | C |

But I'm not sure how I can take those results and map them to SearchFields, to do something like:

```sql
;with cte (searchid, name)
as
(
select 
    max(search.searchid) [SearchId],
    substring(  name, 
                1, 
                len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name))) [Name] 
from search
group by 
    substring( name, 
                1, 
                len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name)))
)
-- this part obviously wrong, not sure how to connect the two
insert into SearchFields(SearchId, Foo)
select c.SearchId, sf.Foo from cte c
union all
select Foo from SearchFields sf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.

```sql
insert into searchfields(searchid, Foo)
select 
(
select top 1 searchid from search where searchid = 
    (select top 1 max(s.searchid) 
     from search s 
     group by 
     substring(name, 1, len(name) - charindex(' ', reverse(name))) 
     having sf.searchid = min(s.searchid))
) [SearchId], Foo
from searchfields sf
order by searchid
```